# Learning transceiver algorithms

Tags: digital-communications, reference-request, digital

I want to learn basic transceiver algorithms.

I already have a good grasp of the mathematics and statistics involved, so I am primarily interested in algorithms.

Any books or site recommendations, so I can start learning?

Comment: Hi! This might be a bit broad in its current form. For me, this sounds like you want a modern textbook on digital communications basics, but I think that won't be of much help if you've not got the DSP basics from a course on signals & systems. So, please be way more specific about what background you have, and what specifically you need to learn.

Answer (score 3):

As Marcus points out, the answer depends on what you mean by "basic". It also depends on whether you already know the math and want to focus on implementations.

If you know how to code, and you've taken an undergrad signals and systems course, but you're just getting started with communications algorithms, I'd recommend "Software Receiver Design" by Sethares et al. Another awesome algorithms book is "Communication System Design using DSP Algorithms" by Tretter.

If you're interested in wireless, "Introduction to wireless communications" by Heath has a great presentation of modern algorithms. If you're primarily interested in LTE, "Understanding LTE with MATLAB" by Zarrinkoub is good.

If you're ready to dig deeper, I'd look at "Wireless communications: an algorithmic approach" by Viletta et al.

To learn a bit more about front-end and software-defined radio algorithms, I can recommend "SDR for engineers" (the author escapes me ATM), and "Digital Signal Processing in Modern Communication Systems" by Schwarzinger.

Bear in mind that these books will not be much use if you don't know how to code, and if you don't already have a good grasp of signals and systems (in which case you should get started with Oppenheim or Haykin) and the underlying communications systems theory and (in which case, maybe start with Haykin).

Comment: SDR for engineers is the book from Analog Devices, right? Travis Collins, Robin Getz, and Alex Wyglinski (hope I spelled that correctly); free PDF on analog.com.

Comment: That's the one. In fact, I learned about this book from one of your posts. https://www.analog.com/en/education/education-library/software-defined-radio-for-engineers.html